# Make bounty background color blue, in the Reputation Summary on the profile page

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, bounties, reputation-summary

Currently, when you are awarded a bounty, the color in the Reputation Summary tab shows up green, just like any other accepted answer or other reputation increase.  This can be a little confusing, like maybe you got five upvotes instead of a bounty.

My request:  Can we make the color show up blue, like this:

[image]

It shows up blue on the post, in the Reputation tab, everywhere else, so making it blue on the profile page would make the user interface better (more consistent?).  It would also differentiate the bounty from accepts and other reputation increases.  Also, if you receive a number of upvotes in addition to that bounty, could we make *all* that show up blue too, like a blue `+80`?  It does that with accepts too (the blue item in the screenshot above is actually an accept, I just fiddled with the CSS).